# Android Retrofit and Mysql: too many connections

Tags: android, mysql, retrofit2

After restarting my Android emulator multiple times (5-10 times), mysql gives me too many connections error. Does Retrofit2 close the connection after the data is fetched?

I dont want to increase the amount of connections by now.

Comment: retrofit is a http client, mysql isn't a http server, so I'm guessing you have something in the middle and that something is actually the thing connecting to mySQL server.

Comment: yes, I have a rest api with express js in the middle. Do you know what causes the problem?

Comment: Your backend probably need to use connection pool I don't know to much about it a quick google gave this https://codeforgeek.com/nodejs-mysql-tutorial/ where they go into it, maybe it will help you.